Ubuntu 22.04 : ryzen desktop with nvidia GPU won't wake up after suspend
My desktop running Ubuntu has the following configuration:
AMD® Ryzen 7 5700x 8-core processor × 16
NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
After a recent update, something must have happened, as when the desktop is suspended, it doesn't wake up again.
I was just using the computer normally and I have no clue what caused the problem to start. Could anybody advise on what are the steps to debug the issue and find out what the problem could be?
Looking for similar questions on the internet, I found the following commands and my execution results are shown below:
➜  ~ sudo dmesg | grep -i tpm
[sudo] password for mvallebr: 
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0xbd46f000 ACPI 2.0=0xbd46f014 TPMFinalLog=0xbd439000 SMBIOS=0xbde22000 SMBIOS 3.0=0xbde21000 MEMATTR=0xb790b698 ESRT=0xb9a16a98 MOKvar=0xbde6b000 RNG=0xbcd76018 TPMEventLog=0xb7890018 
[    0.003697] ACPI: TPM2 0x00000000BCD8B000 00004C (v04 ALASKA A M I    00000001 AMI  00000000)
[    0.003723] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0xbcd8b000-0xbcd8b04b]
[    0.447978] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: Disabling hwrng

➜  ~ journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'
Aug 20 23:08:07 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$startApplication$3.invokeSuspend(startup.kt:171)
Aug 20 23:08:07 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
Aug 20 23:08:07 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$startApplication$3.invokeSuspend(startup.kt:171)
Aug 20 23:08:07 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
Aug 20 23:08:07 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializerKt$computeToolWindowBeans$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:311)
Aug 20 23:08:07 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
Aug 20 23:08:08 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$postEntryProcessing$2.invokeSuspend(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:176)
Aug 20 23:08:08 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$createAndLayoutToolWindows$1.invokeSuspend(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt)
Aug 20 23:08:08 mvallebr-desktop pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop[5593]:         at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
Aug 21 00:50:48 mvallebr-desktop ModemManager[1014]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Aug 21 00:50:48 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724197848.8301] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 21 00:50:48 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724197848.8302] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 21 00:50:48 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724197848.8305] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 21 00:50:48 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724197848.8306] device (wlp5s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 21 00:50:48 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724197848.9704] device (wlp5s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724197849.0099] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop suspend[15132]: nvidia-suspend.service
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop logger[15132]: <13>Aug 21 00:50:49 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop systemd-sleep[15153]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Aug 21 00:50:49 mvallebr-desktop kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 21 07:33:58 mvallebr-desktop kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 21 07:33:58 mvallebr-desktop kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 21 07:33:58 mvallebr-desktop kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Aug 21 07:33:58 mvallebr-desktop kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Aug 21 07:33:58 mvallebr-desktop kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
Aug 21 07:33:58 mvallebr-desktop kernel: PM: suspend exit
Aug 21 07:33:58 mvallebr-desktop systemd-sleep[15153]: System returned from sleep state.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop kernel: CPU: 9 PID: 15242 Comm: nvidia-sleep.sh Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop kernel:  nv_procfs_write_suspend+0x106/0x1c0 [nvidia]
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop kernel: CPU: 9 PID: 15242 Comm: nvidia-sleep.sh Tainted: P        W  OE      6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop kernel:  nv_procfs_write_suspend+0x106/0x1c0 [nvidia]
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Consumed 5.091s CPU time.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2669]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:68
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop suspend[15302]: nvidia-resume.service
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop logger[15302]: <13>Aug 21 07:34:03 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop systemd-logind[970]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop ModemManager[1014]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724222043.3031] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Aug 21 07:34:03 mvallebr-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1724222043.3032] device (enp4s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
-- Boot 89382d6f01434412b20bd6ac4c0ac548 --


